# How to Load Images from Document Directory in iOS8.3+

Tags: objective-c, xcode6.4, ios8.4

**iOS8.4 and Xcode6.4**,
**NOTE:** *database path:*`/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD6CE853-5AE2-48DA-A9B1-E69A6BB4F9F8/data/Containers/Data/Application/BED214A4-65E1-4BD8-9908-29E07FD47EBA/Documents/DB/copybox.db`
*saving time file path:*`/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD6CE853-5AE2-48DA-A9B1-E69A6BB4F9F8/data/Containers/Data/Application/BED214A4-65E1-4BD8-9908-29E07FD47EBA/Documents/Images/010521PMThursdayAug2015.png`
I want to load images from Document Directory.i tried many ways as bellow.

```
NSString*path = [info valueForKey:@"copied_img_path"];
    path = [path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@",path];//
    NSLog(@"\n##IMAGE PATH##:-%@\n",path);
//Tried with this
    [imageview setImageWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
//Tried with this
    NSURL* pathurl = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    [imageview setImageURL:pathurl];
//Tried with this
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [imageview setImage: image];
```

but no success.
then i check file path when i save images in document directory. it is OK. but next time i run this code the current application folder disappears. so, in iOS8.3+ has any change in accessing document directory or i'm making any mistake. please let me know.
**thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `never` save the full path, the `GUID` in the path will change.

Just request the path to the document directory and add the relative file path to the image to this path.